# fast element nodal averaging using numpy

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

I'm using Python 3.6.2 and numpy on Windows.

I have two arrays,

an integer array [I1, I2, I3, I4]

a float value array [VI1, VI2, VI3, Vi4]

The arrays are the same length

The integers in the first array can repeat

The values in the second array are associated to the integer at the same location in the first array.

For every unique integer in the first array, I need to find all of the occurrences of that integer in the first array and then calculate the average of all values at the corresponding location in the second array.

Given an index array [1, 5, 7, 5, 9, 7, 4]

and a value array    [9, 4, 8, 7, 2, 8, 6]

1, 9, and 4 occur once in the index array and are associated with values 9, 2 and 6 which are also the average values for these indices.

5 appears twice in the index array with associated values of 4 and 7 - avg 5.5
7 appears twice in the index array with associated values of 8 and 8 - avg 8.0

The arrays can be very large - up to 100 million.

Of course, this is easy to brute force, but is there a fast and memory efficient way to achieve this in Python/numpy?

Thanks in advance,

Doug

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a numpy `ufuncs` and `np.bincount`:

```
s = np.zeros(i.max())
np.add.at(s, v, i)
c = np.bincount(i)
idx = np.nonzero(c)
out = s[idx] / c[idx]
```

EDIT: As @Divakar, points out, you can just do

```
def nodal_average(i, v):
    s = np.bincount(i, v)
    c = np.bincount(i)
    idx = np.nonzero(c)
    out = s[idx] / c[idx]
    return idx, out
```

Comment: Or simply : `np.bincount(i,v)`?

Comment: Thanks Daniel, thanks Divakar - this is great. I'll try it out on some large data sets tomorrow!!!!

Answer (score 0):

One very simple solution would be to just use Pandas and see how well it scales

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

i = np.array([1, 5, 7, 5, 9, 7, 4])
v = np.array([9, 4, 8, 7, 2, 8, 6])


d = pd.DataFrame({'i': i, 'v': v})
d = d.groupby('i').mean()
```

which gives

```
   v
i     
1  9.0
4  6.0
5  5.5
7  8.0
9  2.0
```